# Orthogonal block matrix made of (signed) permutation matrices

Tags: matrices, reference-request, permutations, orthogonal-matrices, block-matrices

Let $\{P_1, \cdots, P_n\}$ be $n$ permutation matrices with size $n \times n$.

I'd like to build a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix $P$ such that $P^\top P=P P^\top$ is a multiple of the identity, and structured as follows:
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}P_1\,|&\cdots&|\,P_n\\\hline\\ &R&\\&&\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the sign matrix $R \in \{\pm 1\}^{(n^2 - n)\times n^2}$ completes the first $n$ rows of $P$.

My questions are:

- Is it easy to build $R$? What are common possibilities?
- Can $R$ be also made by $n \times n$ blocks, each one being a permutation matrix multiplied by a $\pm 1$?
- Can we relate these blocks to the $P_i$'s of the first block-row?

(Update) Here is a solution I found for $n = 4$, that could help to understand my question.

If $\{P_1, \cdots, P_4\}$ are some permutation matrices of size $2 \times 2$ (or of any square size bigger, actually), then the following matrix is unitary:
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
\ P_1&\ P_2&\ P_3&\ P_4\\
\ P_2&-P_1&-P_4&\ P_3\\
\ P_4&-P_3&\ P_2&-P_1\\
-P_3&-P_4&P_1&P_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Above, the second row is achieved by locally flipping the blocks of the first row, with some sign change rule; the 3rd row is obtained from the 2nd by flipping pair of blocks (and some sign change rule); and the 4th is obtained from the first by again locally flipping block of the 3rd.

My feeling is that the construction above should generalize to any $n$ that is a power of 2. Is there some "butterfly" like method behind? Or, having a look the signs, would it be possible to obtain $P$ from some matrix product of the $\{P_i\}$'s and an Hadamard matrix (but how integrate the flipping of blocks inside)? Many thanks.

Any starting point would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Laurent

Comment: Note that, forgetting the conditions on the entries of $R$, an answer to the question above should work also for any orthonormal matrices $P_1, \cdots, P_n$, not only permutations, since in my example, the only property requested on the $P_i$'s is their orthonormality.

Comment: The structure of $P$ at n=4 above seems connected with the matrix multiplication table of the quaternion, and to Baumert-Hall matrix decomposition, as explained in "Decomposition of Hadamard matrices", by Morris Plotkin. So potentially, there are 48 other equivalent representations of the matrix $P$ above.

Comment: I had another try to find some references for the construction above and was more luck this time. It seems that the matrix P above is connected to "Hadamard Array Based Unitary Matrices", with scalar entries replaced by permutation matrices, see e.g., https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1008468827787.pdf (or http://www.busim.ee.boun.edu.tr/~sankur/SankurFolder/PBOT.ps if you want to skip the paywall)